# Is there a word that means "to give off an odor" (a non-stinky one)?

Tags: single-word-requests

Most of the synonyms on [Thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/smell?s=t) refer to a bad odor.

Is there are word like *reek* which is used to describe good smells?

Example sentence:

> Mary dawdled toward Tom and buried her nose in his school uniform
>   jacket. Despite being new, it already _ his musky scent.

Comment: Emitted is neutral. 'Was redolent of' is also very evocative.

Comment: if you're using words like "musky scent"  you don't necessary need a word that directly means "give off" .. "bore his musky sent" or 'carried' could even work.

Comment: An aroma is a good scent.  Fragrant--e.g., said of flowers--is an adjective for a good scent.

Comment: Yeah. The options are endless on this one. "...it was already infused with his musky scent." Or "bore" like Tom22 said. You can try looking up words in the Thesaurus like infused, emanate, ooze (not really the best word but Thesaurus might lead to other ideas.

Comment: I noticed 'dawdled' was one of the answers to your question about words for 'walking slowly', so i hope you don't mind a comment on its use here. I don't thing 'dawdled' works in this sentence. 'Dawdle' *does* mean move slowly, but mainly carries a connotation of wasting time. It sounds unnatural in here, 'moved slowly towards' would be less jarring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **emanate**. See definition at [MERRIAM WEBSTER](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/emanate)

> to come out from a source. Example: a sweet scent emanating from the blossoms.

... emanated his musky scent.

Answer (score -2):

Odour, scent and perfume are good alternatives.

Comment: Could you add some references as to *why* they could be good alternatives, and that they meet the criteria of being 'non-stinky'? The OP has already suggested 'odor'.